# Equality involving an infinte sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, summation

Can we say that:

$$\frac{1}{(1+a\cos t)^2}=\frac{1}{(1+a)^2}+a\cdot\frac{t^2}{(1+a)^3}+a\cdot\frac{t^4(8a-1)}{12(1+a)^4}+\dots$$

Can we say that those two things are equal?

Answer (score 0):

If the right hand side is supposed to be the Taylor expansion of $(1+a\cos t)^{-2}$, there is a typo in the $t^4$ term: it should be divided by $12$. The equality will hold on the interval of convergence of the series.

Comment: Thanks, I see! But what is the interval of convergence?

Comment: Depends on $a$. The series will converge on the largest interval on which $1+a\cos t\ne0$. The radius of convergence of the series is $|\arccos(-1/a)|$. Observe that if $0<|a|<1$ then $\arccos(-1/a)$ is a complex number.

Comment: I know that $0<a<1$, so what can we conclude?

Comment: In that case $(1+a\cos t)^{-2}$ is analytic on $\Bbb R$, but the radius of convergence of the Taylor series is $|\arccos(-1/a)=\cosh^{-1}(1/a)$.

Comment: So, I know that $a\approx0.0167086$ so for what $t$ is the equality valid?

Comment: For $|t|<4.78491$.